# Excel- function to accept input as coordinates

Tags: excel

Is there a function where I can type the coordinates (eg. B2) and it retrieves the value of the cell B2.
I don't think the function CELL does the trick.

Comment: `=INDIRECT("B2")` will work.  Or just `=B2`

Comment: Thanks, that's sure more simple than I was expecting XD